# Live graph plot from a CSV file with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I followed the [tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/python-matplotlib-live-updating-graphs/) on live graph plot from CSV/TXT file, but when I am running the python program no graph is created, instead, the terminal goes into busy mode until I exit using 'Ctrl+Z'.

For some reason, the animate function in matplotlib is not working for me. Instead I wrote the following code, which is supposed to do the job:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

while True:
    pullData = open("data1.csv","r").read()
    dataArray = pullData.split('\n')
    xar = []
    yar = []
    for eachLine in dataArray:
        if len(eachLine)>1:
            x,y = eachLine.split(',')
            xar.append(x)
            yar.append(y)
    plt.plot(xar, yar)
    plt.pause(0.05)

plt.show()
```

But the above code is not reading the data points from the CSV file properly and generating the wrong graph.

I currently have **Python 3.6.5 :: Anaconda, Inc.** installed on the system. Could someone help in this, please? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [polt Python package](https://pypi.org/project/polt) which I developed for this exact purpose of displaying live data.

Supposing you want to display live **timeseries of multiple data columns in a CSV file**, you could just pipe the live CSV stream (header+live columns) into `polt`:

```sh
(head -n1 myfile.csv; tail -fn0 myfile.csv) | polt add-source -p csv live
```

[image: polt add-source -p csv live]

### Explanation

```sh
(
head -n1 myfile.csv; # output first line of CSV file (header) 
tail -fn0 myfile.csv # output new CSV data continuously
) | polt \ # pipe the data into polt
    add-source -p csv # tell polt to interpret data as CSV
    live # do the live plotting
```

If you do not directly want to plot timeseries, you can check the [polt Animator documentation](https://nobodyinperson.gitlab.io/python3-polt/animators.html) for further displaying possibilities.

Comment: Awesome utility!